# Parked to long 2 years

Tags: honda

I put some good gas in it and I tried to start the car but it wouldn't start does anyone have any suggestions for me to try?

Comment: Can you tell us what you see and hear when you try to start it?

Comment: Have you looked on here for similar questions? Did you charge / replace the battery? Did you push fresh fuel through the system or just put fresh in the tank and the carb still has old fuel?

Comment: Some good points here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1942/10976